# Using REPLACE() in MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql

I apologise in advance for asking what I'm sure will prove to be a very simple question.

I have a MySQL (5.5) database that includes, amongst other things, a field for telephone numbers. I'm trying to create a statement that will search that field, stripping out any spaces. So searching for '0208' will return '020 8', '02 08', '0 208', ' 0208', etc.

And this is in Delphi XE2, in case that makes a difference.

```
'SELECT * FROM sales_ledger WHERE REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") LIKE "%' + SearchEdit.Text + '%"'
```

...gives me an error...

> Invalid filter in WHERE clause

...and...

```
'SELECT REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") FROM sales_ledger WHERE REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") LIKE "%' + SearchEdit.Text + '%"'
```

...gives me...

> Invalid field name. General SQL error. Column not found.

...and I do actually need all fields returned anyway.

May I ask for some assistance in correcting the syntax please. If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask. Thanks very much for your time.

EDIT: One potentially critical piece of information I missed out. The table is actually a Sage database that I'm accessing through ODBC. As nothing I try is working that may well be the root problem. Apologies for not saying that earlier.

Answer (score 10):

Your Query Seems Working Fine see the **[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5111b/3)**

First try this query to you DB Client

```
SELECT * FROM sales_ledger 
WHERE REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") LIKE "%0208%"
```

**EDIT:**

if you query is still not working. fellow step by step process.

- try to run a simple select query (`SELECT * FROM sales_ledger`)
- if the first query run try adding simple where condition.
  so step by step you can make your query similar to original one and find where is the actual error from.

Comment: Still not working Champ but I've edited the original post with more information that may make a difference. Thanks for answering!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM sales_ledger WHERE telephone LIKE "%' + SearchEdit.Text + '%"` - works.

`SELECT * FROM sales_ledger WHERE REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") LIKE "%' + SearchEdit.Text + '%"` - does not work.

Comment: should work. what language you are using. can you give us the code block you are using to execute the query?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, first day back at work...

Using Delphi with this code:

`Query1.Close;
    Query1.SQL.Clear;
    Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM sales_ledger WHERE REPLACE(telephone, " ", "") LIKE "%' + SearchEdit.Text + '%"');
    Query1.Open;`

Answer (score 4):

**Try this ::**

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(telephone,' ', '') as replacedColumn
FROM sales_ledger 


WHERE REPLACE(telephone,' ', '') LIKE '%"+ SearchEdit.Text +"%'"
```

***OR***

```
Select temp1.* 
from
(
SELECT 
REPLACE(telephone,' ', '') as replacedColumn
FROM sales_ledger 
) as temp1

WHERE temp1.replacedColumn LIKE '%"+SearchEdit.Text+"%'"
```

Comment: The first statement returns another 'Column not found' error and the second gets me an 'Invalid table specification' error. I've added information to the original post and apologies for not mentioning it first time. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Now getting 'Table does not exist. General SQL error. Table not found.' Thanks again.

Comment: The first query or the second one?